# Mysql Database shows 'b' in place of bit type field

Tags: mysql

Mysql Table shows value 'b' in place of bit type of data why??
How to convert it again into its original format does anybody know this??

I want values as 0 or 1 in these columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from [Bit-Field Literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-field-literals.html)

> Beginning with MySQL 5.0.3, bit-field values can be written using
>   b'value' or 0bvalue notation. value is a binary value written using
>   zeros and ones.
>
> Bit values are returned as binary values. To display them in printable
>   form, add 0 or use a conversion function such as BIN(). High-order 0
>   bits are not displayed in the converted value.

Comment: Hi Rahul,But values are not stored as 0b or b0 they are stored as b in database how can mysql distinguish between 0 fields and 1 fields as all the fields contain same value i.e. b only. I am not getting this can u please elaborate..??

Comment: Try, adding it as an answer if you feel it's different from what I have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution.

just call value using sql query, 
this query will return only 0 or 1 for bit value though mysql represents value as 'b'.

Need not to worry.

I tried it as "select flag * 4 from table where id = 1" and answer was 0 as 0*4=0.